# MonoGame XNA Helloworld with a Texture2D

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm having some trouble using the Texture2D class. I'm pretty sure this is a fairly easy question. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   1   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    D:\_Projects\MonoGameWindowsApplication1\MonoGameWindowsApplication1\Game1.cs   14  13  MonoGameWindowsApplication1
```

I don't seem to have a reference to the Texture2D class but I'm not sure why I don't. Any help would be great.

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
#endregion

namespace MonoGameWindowsApplication1
{
    private Texture2D background; // <---- This is where I get the above error.

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
            : base()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the `private Texture2D background` variable into the `Game1` class .

Variables must be in a `class`, `interface` or `struct` and not a namespace.

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    private Texture2D background; //Error free
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in a namespace, and it's expecting a class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.

-- Edit: The above poster got it right lol.